# Problemas para renderizar en la tabla exportada con React.js y librería Sheet.js, para ver el valor 'name' (provincia) de la tabla relacionada(fK) grs

Tags: reactjs, excel, sheetjs

Tengo una app en React.js con llamada a la api de laravel por medio de axios, lo que necesito hacer es descargar un excel con los datos de la tabla, lo que si he logrado, pero no logro que se muestre en la tabla el nombre de id_provincia, si se muestra el id como número o integer, pero no logro hacer bien el find() y que relacione el id de la tabla provinces con el de la tabla companies. En teoría, en la función exportToExcel() intento hacer ese filtrado pero hay lógicamente un error. Este es el código:

```React
import {
  getCompanies,
  deleteCompanies,
} from "../../../service/CompaniesService";
import { useEffect, useLayoutEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { getProvinces } from "../../../service/ProvincesService";
import MenuCompanies from "../mol-companies/MenuCompanies";
import * as XLSX from "xlsx";

function classNames(...classes) {
  return classes.filter(Boolean).join(" ");
}

function exportToExcel(selectedCompanies, provinces) {
  let selectedCompaniesForExport = [];
  if (Array.isArray(selectedCompanies)) {
    selectedCompaniesForExport = selectedCompanies.map(
      ({ id, name, email, phone, priority, id_provincia }) => {
        const province = provinces ? provinces.find(p => p.id === id_provincia) : null;
        const provinceName = province ? province.name : '';
        console.log(provinceName); // fixed the console.log statement
        return [id, name, provinceName, email, phone, priority]
      }
    );
    
  }
  const sheet = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(selectedCompaniesForExport, {
    header: ["ID", "Nombre", "ubicación",  "Provincia", "Email", "Teléfono", "Prioridad"],
  });

  const book = {
    Sheets: { data: sheet },
    SheetNames: ["data"],
  };
  const bookType = "xlsx";

  const excelBuffer = XLSX.write(book, {
    bookType: bookType,
    type: "array",
  });

  const blob = new Blob([excelBuffer], { type: "application/octet-stream" });
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = url;
  a.download = "empresas.xlsx";
  a.click();
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}

export default function MolTableDoungLoad() {
  const checkbox = useRef();
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
  const [indeterminate, setIndeterminate] = useState(false);
  const [selectedCompanies, setSelectedCompanies] = useState([]);
  const [companies, setCompanies] = useState([]);
  const [provinces, setProvinces] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getCompanies()
      .then((response) => {
        setCompanies(response.data);
        setSelectedCompanies(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    getProvinces()
      .then((response) => {
        setProvinces(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  }, []);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const isIndeterminate =
      selectedCompanies.length > 0 &&
      selectedCompanies.length < companies.length;
    setChecked(selectedCompanies.length === companies.length);
    setIndeterminate(isIndeterminate);
    checkbox.current.indeterminate = isIndeterminate;
  }, [selectedCompanies, companies]);

  function toggleAll() {
    if (selectedCompanies.length === 0) {
      return;
    }
    setSelectedCompanies(checked || indeterminate ? [] : selectedCompanies);
    setChecked(!checked && !indeterminate);
    setIndeterminate(false);
  }

  function handleDelete() {
    if (selectedCompanies.length === 0) {
      console.warn("No companies selected to delete");
      return;
    }

    // Create an array of promises to delete each selected company
    const deletePromises = selectedCompanies.map((company) =>
      deleteCompanies(company.id)
    );

    // Delete all companies in parallel
    Promise.all(deletePromises)
      .then((responses) => {
        console.log("Companies deleted successfully!");
        // Remove all deleted companies from the e state
        const deletedIds = selectedCompanies.map((event) => event.id);
        setCompanies(companies.filter((e) => !deletedIds.includes(e.id)));
        // Clear the selectedCompanies state
        setSelectedCompanies([]);
        setChecked(false);
        setIndeterminate(false);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(`Error deleting events: ${error.message}`);
      });
  }
  return (
    <>
    <MenuCompanies/>
    <div className="bg-stone6 w-screen max-w-screen-xl rounded-xl p-20 m-20 text-white">
      <div className="sm:flex sm:items-center">
        <div className="sm:flex-auto">
          <h1 className="text-xl font-semibold leading-7">Lista de empresas</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="mt-4 sm:ml-16 sm:mt-0 sm:flex-none">
          <button
            className="text-sm text-stone2 my-10 mx-10 px-6 py-1.5 rounded-xl bg-gradient-to-r from-orangel to-orange hover:from-verde hover:to-verdel ..."
            type="button"
          >
            <a href="/companiescreate">Crear empresa</a>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="mt-8 flow-root">
        <div className="-mx-4 -my-2 overflow-x-auto sm:-mx-6 lg:-mx-8">
          <div className="inline-block min-w-full py-2 align-middle sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            <div className="relative">
              {selectedCompanies.length > 0 && (
                <div className="block left-14 top-0 h-12 items-center space-x-3 sm:left-12">
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="inline-flex items-center rounded px-2 py-1 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900 shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-50 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:opacity-30 disabled:hover:bg-white"
                    onClick={() => handleDelete(selectedCompanies[0].id)}
                  >
                    Eliminar
                  </button>
                </div>
              )}
              <table className="min-w-full table-fixed divide-y divide-gray-300">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col" className="relative px-7 sm:w-12 sm:px-6">
                      <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        className="absolute left-4 top-1/2 -mt-2 h-4 w-4 rounded border-gray-300 text-indigo-600 focus:ring-indigo-600"
                        ref={checkbox}
                        checked={checked}
                        onChange={toggleAll}
                      />
                    </th>
                    <th
                      scope="col"
                      className="min-w-[12rem] py-3.5 pr-3 text-left text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900"
                    >
                      Empresas
                    </th>
                    <th
                      scope="col"
                      className="px-3 py-3.5 text-left text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900"
                    >
                      Ubicación
                    </th>
                    <th
                      scope="col"
                      className="px-3 py-3.5 text-left text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900"
                    >
                      Provncia
                    </th>
                    <th
                      scope="col"
                      className="px-3 py-3.5 text-left text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900"
                    >
                      Email
                    </th>
                    <th
                      scope="col"
                      className="px-3 py-3.5 text-left text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900"
                    >
                      Télefono
                    </th>
                    <th
                      scope="col"
                      className="px-3 py-3.5 text-left text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900"
                    >
                      Prioridad
                    </th>
                    <th
                      scope="col"
                      className="relative py-3.5 pl-3 pr-4 sm:pr-3"
                    >
                      <span className="sr-only">Editar</span>
                    </th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody className="divide-y divide-gray-200 ">
                {companies.map((e) => {
            // Buscar la provincia que corresponde a la empresa actual
                  const province = provinces.find((p) => p.id === e.province_id);
                  return (
                    <tr key={e.id}>
                      <td className="px-7 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                        <input
                          type="checkbox"
                          className="rounded border-gray-300 text-indigo-600 focus:ring-indigo-600"
                          checked={selectedCompanies.includes(e)}
                          onChange={(e) => {
                            const isChecked = e.target.checked;
                            setSelectedCompanies((prev) =>
                              isChecked
                                ? [...prev, e]
                                : prev.filter((c) => c !== e)
                            );
                          }}
                        />              
                      </td>
                      <td
                        className={classNames(
                          "whitespace-nowrap py-4 pr-3 text-sm font-medium",
                          selectedCompanies.includes(e.id)
                            ? "text-indigo-600"
                            : "text-gray-900"
                        )}
                      >
                        {e.name}
                      </td>
                      <td className="whitespace-nowrap px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">
                        {e.ubication}
                      </td>
                      <td className="whitespace-nowrap px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">
                        {province ? province.name : "-"}
                      </td>
                      <td className="whitespace-nowrap px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">
                        {e.email}
                      </td>
                      <td className="whitespace-nowrap px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">
                        {e.phone}
                      </td>
                      <td className="whitespace-nowrap px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">
                        {e.priority}
                      </td>
                      <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-right text-sm font-medium">
                        <Link
                          to={`/companiesedit/${e.id}`}
                          className="text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-900"
                        >
                          Editar
                        </Link>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    );
                    })}
                </tbody>
              </table>
              <button
                  className="inline-flex items-center rounded px-2 py-1 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900 shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-50 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:opacity-30 disabled:hover:bg-white"
                  onClick={() => exportToExcel(selectedCompanies)}
                >
                  Descargar Excel
                </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </>
  );
}
```